# How to remove text in brackets from the start of a string

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I am reading some data from an RSS feed to display on an android device.

The string may or may not have an identifier in brackets at the start e.g.

```
This is a title of something...

[Brochures] This is a brochure title

[Thought Leadership] This is something else
```

I want to remove the identifier from the string if it has one before I display it on the screen. I think regex is the best way but having some trouble getting my head around the syntax.

Any suggestions or solutions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
string.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]","");
```

Comment: Nice one. Just needed to add .trim() to the end of it for exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
String.replaceAll("[.*]","");
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer, as an alternative to RegExp approach :)

```
public static String stripTag(String value) {
    if (value == null || !value.startsWith("[")) {
        return value;
    }
    int closeBracket = value.indexOf(']');
    if (closeBracket < 0) {
        // No closing bracket.
        return value;
    }
    return value.substring(closeBracket + 1).trim();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

regex is the way... but a faster way would be (if the square brackets only appear in the string if the identifier is there, and no brackets appear in the identifier.)

```
String string = "[Thought Leadership] This is something else";
if(string.charAt(0) == '[')
    string = string.substring(string.indexOf("]") + 1).trim();
```

Comment: This replaces only the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Why

```
replaceAll("[", "").replaceAll("]", "")
```

is not good enough?

Comment: This would only replace '[' and ']' characters - not what's in between.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
s=your string
int close=s.lastindexOf(']')
result=s.substring(close+1)
```

Comment: i think this is enough to replace the two brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
String s = "[Thought Leadership] This is something else";
String newString = s.replaceFirst( "\\[[^\\]]+\\]", "").trim();
System.out.println( newString); // Prints: This is something else
```

Answer (score 0):

`myString.replaceFirst("regex", "replacement")` is the method you need.

The regex will be something like `"^\\[.*\\]"` and your replacement string eill be the empty string `""`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regular expression (once escaped into a Java-acceptable format):

```
\[.+\]\s?
```